# Using LINK_REQUIRED parameter with wicked

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ethernet, sles

I'm running SLES 12 and trying to configure network interfaces; this is my first experience with wicked. I'm using "ifup" to up the ethernet devices. I ran into an issue of not being able to ifup the device without a link, basically when there was no physical connection. Some searching led me to this bug report:

https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911562

Then I found this update:

https://www.suse.com/support/update/announcement/2015/suse-ru-20150924-1.html

Specifically this item is what I needed:

- client/nanny: Initial handing of link-detection/require-link and timeout
  control flags (LINK_REQUIRED, LINK_READY_WAIT variables in suse ifcfg)
  to continue setup without ready link when requested in the config or
  based on device requirements (bsc#911562,bsc#914792).

Adding the LINK_REQUIRED=no parameter to my ifcfg-* files resolved the issue. However, I found like to have this parameter be set for **all** network interfaces, so I added it to the /etc/sysconfig/network/config file. This does not seem to work for me, even though wicked documentation I've indicates that it should. I started to search around the source code on GitHub, it looks like it should be applying the parameters in config to all devices.

Has anyone else tried this and got it to work? I am running version 0.6.28, only a couple releases off the latest release (0.6.30).

Thanks in advance.